# Resolution of ILifetimeService fails in autofac 4.6.2

Tags: autofac

We're refactoring an older system to use DI.  Sadly, some of the "core" components that are used all over everywhere have injection unfriendly constructors (descriptions, for example), so we have to use ServiceLocator to create them. Refactoring them is very impractical at this time.

We're trying to create the unfriendly classes by injecting ILifetimeScope into the appropriate place, but are getting the following exception:

`No constructors on type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ScopeRestrictedRegistry' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.`

If I cheat and use the "Update" method on the ContainerBuilder and then register the container as the LifetimeScope, the resolution works successfully, however, given that Update is obsolete, it's not something I want to do.

Can anyone help?

Edit:  I'm not doing anything special.  Build up is standard:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

this.Container = builder.Build();
builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(this.Container);
builder.RegisterInstance(this.Container).As<ILifetimeScope>();
builder.Update(this.Container);
```

Without these lines

```
builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(this.Container);
builder.RegisterInstance(this.Container).As<ILifetimeScope>();
builder.Update(this.Container);
```

any class with an ILifetimeScope dependency fails with the error above.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm actually thinking that this is a bug in the Autofac Framework, so I'm hoping that someone from the team will be able to tell me more.

ILifetimeScope is supposed to automatically be available.

Comment: Need a lot more info like [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Minimal example added above.

Comment: Your example shows a class without an interface. Your assembly scanning only registers things as implemented interfaces. Is the example right?

Comment: MyClass isn't the problem.  The resolution of ILifetimeScope (an internal Autofac thing) is where things fail when trying to resolve ScopeRestrictedRegistry.  The definition of MyClass is really irrelevant, other than the dependencies in its constructor.

Comment: I'm one of the Autofac maintainers. I know what `ILifetimeScope` is. What I was getting at was that if your class wasn't even registered due to a bad assembly scanning setup then the exception you're seeing may be indirectly related. That's why I asked about the class and the interface. If you remove the `ILifetimeScope` parameter from the constructor does it work?

Comment: Yes, works fine without an ILifetimeScope dependency.  Note that the chain of classes being constructed is actually quite deep.  The sample above does not represent the real classes involved (I'll get fired if I list the actual dependencies).  Assume that the classes are registered correctly and that injection is happening correctly for everything EXCEPT ILifeTimeScope, which blows up trying to resolve Autofac.Core.Registration.ScopeRestrictedRegistry, unless the container is Updated with ILifetimeScope added.

Comment: Folks can't get you an answer if we can't see an actual repro of what's going on.

Comment: Ever get this working? Thanks